# How to get URL of currently opened webpage of Chrome application desktop shortcut

Tags: windows, google-chrome, desktop, url

A [quick google](https://www.google.com/search?q=How%20to%20get%20URL%20of%20currently%20opend%20webpage%20of%20Chrome%20application%20shortcut&oq=How%20to%20get%20URL%20of%20currently%20opend%20webpage%20of%20Chrome%20application%20shortcut&aqs=chrome..69i57.287j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) on my need "How to get URL of currently opend webpage of Chrome application shortcut" give me nothing helpful.

So what is the fastest get the URL of an [Chrome application desktop shortcut](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95710?hl=en-GB)? In a browser, we simply copy the address bar.

p.s.

For example, let's say we create an application shortcut for this site at URL superuser.com; then we open it, and browse to this answer. At that moment, I want to share the page, and need to copy the URL of the `currently opened` website in front of my eye. I don't know how to right there.

Comment: Are these app shortcuts normal .LNK files just like shortcuts you create? Also, how do you define 'quickly'? Isn't the URL quickly available from the page info? Moreover, your question is slightly vague. You say you want the URL of the shortcut, but you also say you want the URL of the *currently opened page* of the shortcut. So if you created a shortcut to SU's homepage and navigated here for example, the two things you mentioned would be different, right? So which is it? Be clear please.

Comment: Yes, it is a .lnk file like shortcuts.

Comment: @Karan Thank you. I have updated my OP to reflect your question.

Comment: `Quickly` is just my word when asking; maybe the fastest way to do that is what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to answer this question. OP is asking for "Chrome Application", it can be created from Chromes menu->`More tools->Create application shortcuts`.

Once click this shortcut(its different from .url) it will open the URL in chrome but without address bar, menu button etc.. Here is a screenshot, desktop application and chrome side by side.

[image]

So locating to address bar then ctrl+c wouldn't work. The only way I found, without an extension, is to use "View Page Source"(right click or Ctrl+U), with which, you get back to the standard chrome page with an address bar, then "ctrl+L, ctrl+C" will work, just need to remove the "view-source" from the copied content.

Comment: This is promising ^^. I'll try on my PC and soon back with you later.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2019-06-11, on Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169, you can click the ... on the top right corner, and you'll see a menu item called "Copy URL". See screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Highlight the address bar using **<kbd>Control</kbd>** + **<kbd>L</kbd>**
2. Copy the address URL using **<kbd>Control</kbd>** + **<kbd>L</kbd>**

Comment: please delete answer: no address bar means Ctrl-l can not work

Comment: @Furty: (1) Feel free to post comments identifying issues, but please don’t ask that answers be deleted.   When you get to 125 rep, you will be able to down vote answers that you believe to be flawed.   If a post is abusive (personal attacks, hate speech, etc.), flag it.   (2) I’m not sure why you say “no address bar”.   I find the question to be just about incomprehensible, but I do not see where it says “no address bar”.

Comment: The question says "In a browser, we simply copy the address bar." - which means in a website that was "appified" by Chrome there is no address bar. Also see the top answer and answer before John. Which means John sort of duplicated the already inaplicable answer from Divin3 (and even if there was an address bar, line 2 would be wrong).

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I submitted an edit to the question to add a screenshot for the given example.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a solution with a chrome extension, here it is.

1. Get a chrome extension that copies all urls of all tabs (This will work because the "Chrome Application" counts as a single tab in one window).

   - The one I tested is [Copy All Urls](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-all-urls/djdmadneanknadilpjiknlnanaolmbfk/related?hl=en)
2. Then go `chrome://extensions/` scroll to to the bottom, click on `Keyboard Shortcuts`. Set the hotkey for the copy and paste of the extension. I chose `Ctrl + Shift + C` for copy and `Ctrl + Shift + V` for paste.
3. Now when you have the "Chrome Application" open and in focus, use the hotkeys you set to copy the URL. Note that since it will be a single URL you can just use the default `Ctrl + V` to paste the URL

Other than that you will have to use the "view source" method that Chris.C described.

Side note, I swear in old versions of Chrome there was a `Right-click on title bar, "Open in Browser"` menu. Now there is just `Right-click on title bar "Open Browser Window"` which just opens a blank tab. Anyone else remember this? This change in behaviour is the reason I looked up this super user question in the first place.